# MS SQL vertical partitioning

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I want to implement vertical partitioning in Microsoft sql server and tried following steps,

Step 1

```
ALTER DATABASE [mydatabase] ADD FILEGROUP DATA_1
```

Step 2

```
ALTER DATABASE [mydatabase]
ADD FILE ( NAME = [fileData-1], FILENAME = 'D:\xxx\filedata.ndf')
TO FILEGROUP DATA_1
```

Step 3

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[partitionedtable1](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [value1] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[partitionedtable2](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [value1] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [DATA_1]
```

when i check above table in sys.partitions table still it shows partition_number as 1

further i can do above using if i needed partition based on textimage.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[partitionedtable1](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [value1] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
      [value2] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [DATA_1]
```

Is it possible to have one single table for below with partitioned columns in two data files

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[partitionedtable1](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [value1] int NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[partitionedtable2](
  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [value2] int (max) NOT NULL
) ON [DATA_1]
```

Comment: Those aren't partitions, which is why they don't appear in `sys.partitions`. It's just two tables with no relation to each other. The data have nothing in common either, as the *primary keys* have automatically generated *different* values.

Comment: What is your reason for vertical partitioning? If your goal is to improve performance of scans, consider columnstore.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you think you need vertical partitioning? If it is to store BLOBs/CLOBs separately, [FILESTREAM storage and FileTables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/binary-large-object-blob-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) do that already

Comment: @DanGuzman speaking of which compare [this](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3719221/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server.htm) and [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-should-we-store-images-and-blob-files-in-sql-server/). Calling FiLESTREAM a `new feature` in a 2019 article is a bit of a giveaway

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Filestream isn't a new SQL 2019 feature, although the referenced article is written this year. Similar feature discussion in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/compare-options-for-storing-blobs-sql-server).

Comment: @DanGuzman I had something that starts with `pla` and end with `giarism` in mind. The "new" article is the same except for small wording changes to the second article from 2008. That *MVP* didn't even think to fix the dates

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it is very sad when anyone uses someone else's work without crediting the original author.